# How can I detect shift presses that occurred outside of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The keypress events trigger when I have the page in focus, through `$(document).keyup` and `$(document).keydown`, however, when I press a key outside of the page (i.e. I click on the taskbar, and then press and hold shift, and then bring the page back into focus by clicking on it) the event doesn't fire.

Is there any way of getting the state of these keys when the window is brought back into focus?

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/85kkwwjh/)

EDIT: To clarify, I want to know if the shift key is pressed when I click a button, but I cannot rely on keydown / keyup events.

Comment: with me it is all the time working

Comment: You probably can't. You'd need a program outside the browser to capture the keypress. If the browser is not in focus, it won't listen to your keypresses.

Comment: So there is no way to check the key presses on, say, a click event or on setInterval?

Comment: @YehiaAwad Try clicking on the desktop, holding  shift, and then clicking back on the page

Comment: you want the click that is outside the browser to be listened by it ?

Comment: No, I want to be able to check if shift is pressed when I click on an element on the page, but I want to be able to do this without the key events